# Is there any way to know the distance between the camera and the focused subject

Tags: subject-distance, focus-distance, distance-markers

I am using **Nikon D3500** but the question may be of a general nature.
I understand that the Camera measures distance between the subject in focus and the Camera for deciding the flash light requirements and other parameters. Is this **ACTUAL distance** information displayed on the screen in live view or in the view finder when we put the shutter release button half way down.

*(An illustrative image will be more helpful in understanding)*

Comment: Subject distance is not the controlling factor for flash. TTL flash control fires the flash then cuts it off when it decides enough light has been seen. If the subject is too far away, the flash reaches it's full energy limit and ends with insufficient light.

Answer (score 2):

It's saved in the exif data when the photograph is taken, as *Focus Distance*, but I know of no way to access it directly from the camera, either before or after taking the shot.

Comment: I think this does not answer the question: The question is about how to view the 'actual distance' on a certain camera in the moment of the shoot. It is not about how to retrieve the information after the image was taken.

Comment: @quiliup - I could have just written "This cannot be done." with no further information at all. Would that have better satisfied your criterion for it being "an answer"?

Comment: The focus distance in the Exif data is often seriously incorrect, especially in zoom lenses and/or internal focusing lenses, which are continuously modifying the lens geometry.  My complaint is that it seriously affects the TTL BL flash accuracy.  My site has charts of this for of some Nikon lenses, at https://www.scantips.com/lights/ttlbl-d.html#3

Comment: @WayneF - I was unaware of the **BL** distance factor. This seems odd to me as the lens distance and flash distance would only be the same for on-camera flash.

Comment: Yes, same distances for camera direct flash. But Nikon TTL BL flash mode (and Canon has a version) uses the reported lens distance to prevent overexposure of direct flash metering a dark background (beyond flash range) that would commonly cause overexposure (trying to brighten the dark background). That seems reasonable, except that it fails when the actual distance is more than the lens distance reports, which judges the flash power should be less causing actual underexposure (No lens correction is attempted for metered underexposure).  My link above has examples.

Comment: @Tetsujin I presume there could be a way to do it by keeping the camera tethered, monitoring filesystem changes on the internal card, and then using ExifTool to determine the distance from a "test photo" that is taken, then displayed on an external display. Or perhaps there's some third-party firmware that has this stuff available, although I am not aware of any

Comment: @SkeletonBow - I can think of all kinds of Heath Robinson ways to grab the info, but I'm sure it would be simpler to carry a tape or a laser measure ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I had difficulty in understanding it. But surely one day I will revisit to understand it after I learned my basics and advance skills in photography.
In the meantime, I did tried to extract the 'exif' data' from the test pictures of my Nikon D3500 after transferring it to my PC. I used this online site http://metapicz.com/#landing
However, it turned all exif data as 'not found'
Location : GPS coordinates not found.
EXIF : EXIF data not found.
XMP : XMP data not found.
Maker Notes : Maker Notes data not found.
.... .... ...